# Python3 Pip Not Working on My Pi

Tags: python, pip

So I was having some trouble with python package incompatibilities.  I was tired of troubleshooting and decided that I would remove all of the packages that I had installed using pip3.  In an attempt to do this, I stupidly removed all files under the `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages` directory using this command:

`sudo rm -R /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/*`

After doing this, I tried to use pip3 to reinstall the packages that I needed, but all of a sudden, the pip3 command would not work and instead display a lengthy error message.  I tried uninstalling and reinstalling python3-pip and python-pip, but the error would not go away.  At this point, I don't know what to do to fix pip3, so I would really appreciate any help with helping to understand the error message, and to fix the problem.  Here is the error message that I get when I try to install any package using pip3 (I get the same error when I use pip as well):

```
`Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 143, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 279, in run
    with self._build_session(options) as session:
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 79, in _build_session
    insecure_hosts=options.trusted_hosts,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/download.py", line 337, in __init__
    self.headers["User-Agent"] = user_agent()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/download.py", line 100, in user_agent
    zip(["name", "version", "id"], distro.linux_distribution()),
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/distro-1.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/distro.py", line 120, in linux_distribution
    return _distro.linux_distribution(full_distribution_name)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/distro-1.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/distro.py", line 675, in linux_distribution
    self.version(),
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/distro-1.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/distro.py", line 735, in version
    self.lsb_release_attr('release'),
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/distro-1.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/distro.py", line 892, in lsb_release_attr
    return self._lsb_release_info.get(attribute, '')
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/distro-1.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/distro.py", line 550, in __get__
    ret = obj.__dict__[self._fname] = self._f(obj)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/distro-1.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/distro.py", line 998, in _lsb_release_info
    stdout = subprocess.check_output(cmd, stderr=devnull)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 395, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 487, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '('lsb_release', '-a')' returned non-zero exit status 1.`
```

Here are the results of running `pip3 -V`:

`pip 18.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.7)`

I don't know if that information would be useful, but I figured that I would include it.  Once again, I would really appreciate any help in understanding the error and fixing the issue.  Thanks for any responses in advance!

Answer (score 2):

So I was able to fix the issue by uninstalling python and autoremoving and then reinstalling python:

`sudo apt-get purge python python3 python-pip python3-pip`

`sudo apt autoremove`

`sudo apt-get install python python3 python-pip python3-pip`

Unfortunately, I still don't know exactly what caused the issue, but this approach did solve the issue for me.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Answer (score 1):

You must reinstall everything that has connection with python2 and python3. This can fix your problem.